# selenium webdriver click link in the tag

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<div id="sbGlobalNav" class="">
  <div id="sbGlobalNavContent">
    <div id="sbGlobalNavRightContent">...</div>
    <div id="sbGlobalNavLeftContent">
 <a href="/" id="globalNavSBLogo"></a>
       <ul id="globalNavMenu">
     <li class="globalNavSeparator firstSeparator">..</li>
     <li>..</li>
     <li>..</li>
     <li>..</li>
     <li>..</li>
     <li class="globalNavDropdown">
    <span>Answer</span>
    <ul class="globalNavDropdownContainer" style="display: none;">
        <li>..</li>
        <li><a href="/p/polls" class="navIconPolls">Daily Polls</a></li>
        <li>..</li>
    </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="globalNavDropdown">..</li>
     <li class="globalNavSeparator">..</li>
     <li class="globalNavDropdown" id="globalNavRewards">..</li>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

In this I need to find and click Daily Poll link using Selenium webdriver(java) but I was unable to do it.
What I did is:

```
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sbGlobalNav']//span[text()='Answer']"))).build().perform();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Daily Polls")).click();
```

Comment: what version of driver and browser?

Answer (score 0):

Check it, whether you have to so something to trigger that element out. Javascript maybe, by mouse over ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Daily Polls']")).click();
```

It might work.